# Can index creation use existing indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have individual indexes on, say, columns A, B and C. I'd like to create a composite index on the three columns A+B+C.

What impact will my **existing** indexes have on composite index **creation**? Will the database take advantage of them, are they irrelevant, or will they slow down the creation of my new composite index?

I'm using MySql 5.1.

**EDIT**: BTW the table has several million rows.

**EDIT 2**: thanks to tster for the suggestion: I tried this out on a much smaller table (admittedly just 20,000 rows) but even so the creation of a new composite index took noticeably longer when the individual indexes were already present.

Comment: iirc, MySQL only uses one index.  I'd create the covering/composite index myself, and get rid of the individual ones

Comment: @OMGPonies: thanks for your comment. Would you ditch the individual ones first, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Why not create the index with the three indexes there and time it, then do the same without the indexes there and see if one is faster.  My guess is that there will be no difference since scanning three indexes and then merging them together is probably more expensive than scanning the entire relation.

Comment: I find it amazing that it took longer with the individual indexes there.  I am extremely curious to know why that is happening.

Comment: "Several million rows" doesn't sound like that much, you can probably rebuild the table within 30 minutes (depending on your exact data). The difficult ones are where it takes hours to create an index. If the table fits in ram, creating the indexes is relatively quick. Your server should have enough ram for a table of "several million rows"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL usually rebuilds the whole table when you add an index, so all the existing ones get rebuilt as well. This can be slow.

The only exception is adding an index using the InnoDB plugin, which does not.

As far as I know, it always does a full table scan when building an index, however it COULD do an index scan if you were adding an index which had the same (or a subset) of columns as another index. Such indexes are normally only useful if the columns are in a different order.

Using stock mysql, the more indexes you have, the slower it will be to make a new one, as it rebuilds existing indexes too.

With the plugin, I think it makes no difference.

Either way, if you're planning to add several indexes, you should do them all-at-once not one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing indexes are not relevant to the *creation* of the new index.  An index is a physical thing on disk and you're asking the database to create a brand new one which has an entirely different structure from the existing three.

(Caveat: I have no specific knowledge of MySQL.)