# Does existing index count influence index creation time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Example: Table A has 10 columns (4 indexed) and 200 million rows. I'm adding a 5th index. Should I expect it to take longer to add it than the first index?

[Can index creation use existing indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795189/can-index-creation-use-existing-indexes)
This is related but it's about mysql though. Is it the same in postgres?

Comment: No, `create index` does not use any other indexes.

Comment: The time is more related to how many and wide the keys are in the index.